# Why does SVG image loads on redirect in the same div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

i got unusual situation. I got svg file loaded in object.

```
<div class="bg">
      <object id="svg1" data="/nejc/bg_index_svg.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
      Your browser doesn't support SVG
      </object>
 </div>
```

And i got script in svg file inside CDATA

```
var val = document.getElementById("placeid");
      val.addEventListener("click", function() {
      document.location.href ="index_library.php";
}, false);
```

When i click on element which i get in variable "val" the browser wont redirect to index-library.php but it loads the page it would have to redirect in the same div .bg

Did anyone have similar problem?

Comment: it works for me.use your javascript part inside load function.

Comment: window location does the same. also does when wrapped in window.onload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple asnwer was to add svg image inside php document as inline element. Then it redirects properly. It is the only solution that worked for me, but that was not exactly what i wanted.